# Reading values of SPI data register of STM32 MCU

Tags: c, embedded, hardware, stm32, spi

There are quite a few similar questions, but none seem to have quite the same issue. I am connecting an STML4 MCU to a 6-axis sensor (LSM6DS3).  I have successfully implemented everything in I2C, but would like the extra speed of SPI (and DMA, if I can get these first steps working...). So for a first step, I am trying to read the `WHO_AM_I` register (`0x0F`) of the device, which should reply with `0x69`. Here is the code:

```
uint8_t who = 0;

// Sanity check/debugging aid should get 0x5D
who = 0x43 + 0x1A;

// Set SS low
GPIO_WritePin (GPIOB, LL_GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

// while tx buffer is in use, wait
while (!LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_TXE(SPI1));

// Send READ command to the WHO_AM_I register
(SPI1->DR) = 0x8F;

// while rx buffer is in use, wait
while (!LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(SPI1));

// Get data off the register
who = (SPI1->DR);

// Wait for everything to wrap up before setting SS high again
while (LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_BSY(SPI1));

// OK, now we can set SS high
GPIO_WritePin (GPIOB, LL_GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

On the scope/analyzer, I see everything run as expected, including the sensor sending back `0x69`. However, when I set a break on the other side of this code block, I see that `who` goes from `0` to `0x5D` to `0xFF`. It never reads the `0x69`. I looked through other code examples and some people have a second transmit with the data set to some dummy value (usually `0xFF` or `0x0`), so I also tried that, but the sensor seems to get confused during the second attempt and `who` ends up being `0x48`. I have tried every permutation of waiting for the `RXNE`/`TXE`/`BSY` flags that I could have, as well as many many other things to get the variable to correctly read the `SPI1` data register, including reading other registers off the sensor, but all to no avail.

So then the question is, how does one correctly read values off this register?

I should also mention that I can successfully write to the device's registers. I can send the command I want, then read it back and see that it worked on the scope, even though I can never get the values assigned to a variable in code. I always get `0xFF`.

I include a screen of my analyzer showing the sensor sending back `0x69` from a single read request, as well as the garbled mess it sends if I try the "dummy transmit" method.[image: Correcly sending me the WHO_AM_I value] [image: Sending back <code>0x48</code> on "double" transmit]

Answer (score 3):

SPI always (if the receiver is enabled) receives the data when you transfer.

This is the problem with the libraries that you do not know what is there. SPI is a lot easier to program using registers.

I assume that your data is 8bits.

You need to set the 1/4 (one byte) FIFO threshold during the SPI initialization by:

```
 SPI1 -> CR2 |= SPI_CR2_FRXTH;
```

next you need to read the data from the FIFO after every write (you need also to force the compiler to use the correct size (in this case 8bits) load and store instructions):

```
*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = 0x8F;  // write exactly 8 bits to the FIFO
while (!LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(SPI1));
dummy = *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI-> DR;
*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = 0;  // dummy write
while (!LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(SPI1));
who = *(volatile uint8_t *)&(SPI1->DR);
```

I do not know what is the point of using the LL libraries.

instead of

```
while (!LL_SPI_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(SPI1));
```

use registers

```
while (!(SPI1 -> SR & SPI_SR_RNE));
```

You can also wrap it into the function:

```
uint8_t SPI_ReadWrite8(SPI_TypeDef *spi, uint8_t data)
{
    while(!(spi -> SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    *(volatile uint8_t *)&spi->DR = data; 
    while (!(spi -> SR & SPI_SR_RNE));
    return *(volatile uint8_t *)&spi-> DR;
}
```

And

```
SPI_ReadWrite8(SPI1, 0x8f);
who = SPI_ReadWrite8(SPI1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually done everything you mention here except for setting the quarter FIFO threshold. The only reason I gave it in LL form above was for clarity. I've also tried it in it's own function, I just thought it would be easier to have it all in the same code block here. However, I gave it a try just as you have it here (fixing the type in the function - it should be `RXNE`), and I get almost the same response, although now `who` is set to `0x0` in the end. The scope signal looks the same though.

Comment: did you set the threshold?

Comment: do you use *(volatile uint8_t *) access?

Comment: Yes and yes. However, I just got it to work. For some reason, replacing `SPI_SR_RXNE` with `SPI_SR_BSY` gives me the correct value. I don't suppose you might have some insight into how that would be the difference?

Comment: did you set the DS? (`SPI1 -> CR2 &= ~(SPI_CR2_DS_Msk);
SPI1 -> CR2 |= 0b111 << SPI_CR2_DS_Pos;`)

Comment: You had something in the FIFO - that is the reason. flush it. while(IP1 -> SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) dummy =  *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;

Comment: Yes I had already been doing that. Since your response seems to have led me to the correct answer, If you modify it to have `SPI_SR_BSY` instead of `SPI_SR_RNE` I will accept it as the answer. Bonus points if you can explain why it works that way.

Comment: It works because it flushes another data. But it is not the correct way. On same STMs BSY is cleared earlier than the data data from the receive shift register is transferred to the data register. To detect data use RXNE. If it does not work for some reasons - it is indication of another problem you have in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177293/discussion-between-trivialcase-and-p-j).